# PHP - realpath not working; file definitely exists

Tags: php

I'm attempting to use [realpath()](http://php.net/realpath) to avoid a directory traversal attack, and I can't quite figure out why it's returning false on a file that definitely exists.

The files are being hosted on an NFS share that the Apache user has access to. The entire hierarchy is 755, except for the file itself which is 777.

Here's a code snippet:

```
$path = "/mnt/share/path/to/20160111-133552-msg0000.wav";
$path = realpath($path);
var_dump($path);
```

The result is:

```
bool(false)
```

The file is definitely there. I su-ed into the Apache user and ran:

```
bash-4.2$ ls -lah /mnt/share/path/to/20160111-133552-msg0000.wav
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 1001 1001 77K Jan 11 13:35 /mnt/share/path/to/3000-20160111-133552-msg0000.wav
```

One other observation: When I remove the filename from the $path variable:

```
$path = "/mnt/share/path/to/
```

it works just fine:

```
string(39) "/mnt/share/path/to"
```

Anyone ran into this behavior before?

Comment: On the PHP manual page for realpath, this note exists:
The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE. http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: Don't you have to give realtive path to realpath() function ?
i.e realpath("../../../20160111-133552-msg0000.wav");

Comment: @ckimbrell The entire hierarchy is 755, except for the file itself which is 777.

Comment: in Unix, the "x" permission is required to list the contents of a directory. So the `to/` directory will need to have `777`

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured this one out on my own! Good ol' selinux was preventing httpd from accessing the file:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1452550767.071:18495): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=10397 comm="httpd" name="3000-20160111-133552-msg0000.wav" dev="0:41" ino=12483 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=file
    Was caused by:
    One of the following booleans was set incorrectly.
    Description:
    Allow httpd to use nfs

    Allow access by executing:
    # setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs 1
```

I only discovered this when I tried to do a readfile() on the .wav file in question and got a permission denied error, which didn't make sense on a 777 file. Checked /var/log/audit/audit.log and it was obvious.

Running `setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs 1` fixed it right up for me.

Answer (score -1):

*Don't take the following for true: this answer was written based on a misremember of the detailed combination of the access rights: 755 already allows execution for all!*

---

You said:

> The entire hierarchy is 755, except for the file itself which is 777.

While the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) says:

> The running script must have **executable** permissions on **all** directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE.

So you'd set the entire hierarchy to 777 to this `realpath()`to work.

Comment: 755 = rwxr-xr-x. The apache user falls into other, so they have r-x. Is write permission really needed in this case?

Comment: @csyria. Oops, you're definitely right. I misremembered the detailed combination! I edit my answer to avoid giving false information...

Comment: Thanks for that update @cFreed - I thought I was going crazy on my memory of how Linux file permissions worked! :)